# ArgParse argument value not accessible

Tags: julia

I am not able to access the `ArgParse`'s `opt2` value with the following code

```
using ArgParse
function parse_commandline()
    s = ArgParseSettings()
    @add_arg_table s begin
        "--opt2"
            help = "another option with an argument"
            arg_type = Int
            default = 0
            required = true
    end
    return parse_args(s)
end

@show parsed_args = parse_commandline()
    println("Parsed args:")
    for (arg,val) in parsed_args
        print("  $arg  =>  ")
        show(val)
        println()
    end
    println(opt2)



$ julia test.jl --opt2 7
parsed_args = parse_commandline() = Dict{String,Any}("opt2" => 7)
Parsed args:
  opt2  =>  7
ERROR: LoadError: UndefVarError: opt2 not defined
Stacktrace:
 [1] top-level scope at /Users/lorencm/projects/bioinf-scripts-julia/test.jl:72
 [2] include at ./boot.jl:328 [inlined]
 [3] include_relative(::Module, ::String) at ./loading.jl:1105
 [4] include(::Module, ::String) at ./Base.jl:31
 [5] exec_options(::Base.JLOptions) at ./client.jl:287
 [6] _start() at ./client.jl:460
in expression starting at /Users/lorencm/projects/bioinf-scripts-julia/test.jl:72
```

What did I miss?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`opt2` is not a variable name. You have to key the `parsed_args` dictionary:

```
julia> parsed_args["opt2"]
7
```